# Elasticsearch index data exists and can be queried against but the returned json is blank

Tags: templates, search, elasticsearch, mapping, logstash

I suspect I'm making a newbie mistake.

I have an elasticsearch index (lswl) that is accepting data from logtash and winlogbeat that has indexed (not_analyzed) data but I can't seem to retrieve it.

When I run the following query

```
POST /lswl-2016.08.15/_search?pretty
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

I get the following results:

```
      "hits": {
      "total": 9,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "lswl-2016.08.15",
            "_type": "wineventlog",
            "_id": "AVaLgghl49PiM_pqlihQ",
            "_score": 1
         }
```

I know there's data in there because queries like this return a subset of values.

```
POST /lswl-*/_search?pretty
{
    "query": {
        "term": { "host": "BTRDAPTST02"}
    }
}
```

I suspect that the problem is in the template I created for the the lswl index but for the life of me I can't figure out what I did incorrectly.  The template is below for reference.

```
    "template": "lswl*",
    "settings":{
        "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
        "wineventlog":{
            "_source": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
               "@timestamp": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
               },
               "@version": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "category": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "computer_name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "count": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "event_id": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "host": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "level": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "log_name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "message": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                      "original": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                      }
                  }
               },
               "record_number": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "source_name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "tags": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "type": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "user": {
                  "properties": {
                     "domain": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "identifier": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the following part or set it to true

```
        "_source": {
            "enabled": false
        },
```

And then delete the index and re-index your data. You'll be able to see the data afterwards.

Comment: I did that and it started showing up.  I'm a little confused though, I thought _source was just used to store a record of the original data.  Can you not return fields without _source even though you can still search against them?

Comment: Yes, you can but you need to specify [`store: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html) in the fields you'd like to store (by default fields are not stored since the source is stored), then you can retrieve them in your query by specifying `"fields": ["field1", "field2"]`.

Comment: Thanks Val, much appreciated!